# how do you load an rtf into a UIWebView with a clear background

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview

I want to load an rtf into a web view with a clear background. The general consensus on creating a UIView with a clear background requires adding html code to set the background-color:transparent like this...

```
myWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
mytWebView.opaque = NO;
[yWebView loadHTMLString:@"<html><head><style>body{background-color:transparent;}</style> </head><body>your content here!</body></html>" baseURL:nil];
```

How do I format the HTML string to include the rtf.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 1):

You can load the html inside of an NSString using the `stringWithFormat method. Assuming a string called`rtf` that holds the contents of your RTF, simply use the following line:

```
[yWebView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><style>body{background-color:transparent;}</style> </head><body> %@ </body></html>", rtf] baseURL:nil];
```

Note the `%@` where your RTF goes and the nested `stringWithFormat:` call.

Comment: You say rtf is a string that holds the contents of the RTF. Do you mean the path to the file or the actual contents. I want the RTF with it's formatting to display just as it would if I loaded it directly but with a clear background.

Comment: I have tried using the path, and the NSURL directly between the body tag which just displays the path or NSURL. I've tried php include as well and it displays nothing. If the name of the file is myRTF.rtf what goes between the body tags? Basically I want to get the same thing I get with loadRequest, but with a clear background.

Comment: The more I search for a solution the more I think it can only be done with the content of the rtf. Using the content, however, instead of formatted text you get the rtf format code along with the text. Am I wrong here? I could use a pdf instead of the rtf, but I have the same problem trying to get the pdf to display with a clear background.

Comment: The actual contents of the RTF goes in the string. To be honest, I've never loaded an RTF, but now that I think about it, you probably want an `NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:`.

Comment: stringWithContentsOfFile works but fine with a txt and you can easily set the background to clear with [UIColor clearColor), but with an RTF you do not get any formatting, instead you get the formatting code. The only way I know to get the rtf with formatting is in a UIWebView and the only way to get the clear background that I have found is with a combination of [UIColor clearColor] and the html string with color:transparent. I am giving up and abandoning the need to have any formatting. Thanks for your help.